# Solutions to Non-linear equation system

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I have been trying to solve the following system of equations:

```
0.0345333 (0.23 + x) - 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) == 
1.6*10^-19 (10^16 - 8.15658*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 x)]);

0.0345333 (-0.62 - y) + 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) == 
1.6*10^-19 (10^16 + 6.88347*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 y)]);
```

Log=e based logarithm

I used NSolve, no answer was given although the evaluation was running.
Later I turned to FindRoot and faced similar results.

I am new to Mathematica and never used it before. I will really appreciate any possible help from anyone regarding the solution of these equations.

Thanks in advance.

Kanak
Dept. of EEE, BUET

Comment: Strange, I get error messages, can you post the code you are using ?

Answer (score 6):

Let us first give names to your equations:

```
    eq1 = 0.0345333 (0.23 + x) - 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) == 
   1.6*10^-19 (10^16 - 8.15658*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 x)]);

eq2 = 0.0345333 (-0.62 - y) + 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) == 
   1.6*10^-19 (10^16 + 6.88347*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 y)]);
```

Now a good idea would be to plot them. For that let us resolve the first equation with respect to y and the second - to x:

```
    sl1 = Solve[eq1, y]
sl2 = Solve[eq2, x]

(*  {{y -> 16.1348 (0.0340879 - 0.061978 x - 0.0345333 (0.23 + x) + 
      1.6*10^-19 (1.*10^16 - 8.15658*10^16 Log[1. + E^(-38.61 x)]))}}

{{x -> -16.1348 (-0.0340879 - 0.0345333 (-0.62 - 1. y) + 0.061978 y + 
      1.6*10^-19 (1.*10^16 + 6.88347*10^16 Log[1. + E^(-38.61 y)]))}}  *)
```

Now we can plot them:

```
  Show[{
  Plot[sl1[[1, 1, 2]]
   , {x, -0.1, 0.1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}],
  ParametricPlot[{sl2[[1, 1, 2]], y}, {y, -0.1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

[image]

Now it is clear, where to take the initial values for the numeric calculation:

```
 FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -0.04}, {y, 0.12}]

(*  {x -> -0.0406988, y -> 0.140409}  *)
```

and

```
FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -0.07}, {y, -0.05}]

(* {x -> -0.0724718, y -> -0.0411336}  *)
```

Done. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

With `ContourPlot` one can find easily the roots.

```
eq1 = 0.0345333 (0.23 + x) - 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) 
- (1.6*10^-19 (10^16 - 8.15658*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 x)]));

eq2 = 0.0345333 (-0.62 - y) + 0.061978 (0.55 - x - y) 
- (1.6*10^-19 (10^16 + 6.88347*10^16 Log[1 + E^(-38.61 y)]));

ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -0.1, 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
sol1 = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -1}, {y, -1}]
(* {x -> -0.0724718, y -> -0.0411336} *)

sol2 = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -1}, {y, 1}]
(* {x -> -0.0406988, y -> 0.140409} *)

{eq1, eq2} /. sol1
(* {1.38778*10^-17, -3.46945*10^-18} *)

{eq1, eq2} /. sol2
(* {6.93889*10^-18, -1.95156*10^-18} *)
```

**Edit**

For completeness:
With Stan Wagon's `FindRoots2D` in "Mathematica in Action" we get all roots in a given interval.

```
roots = FindRoots2D[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
(* {{-0.0724718, -0.0411336}, {-0.0406988, 0.140409}} *)
```

[image]